# When UIButton is pressed and IBAction is called show UIAlertView with activity indicator in it until done

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a very simple yet annoying question. I have two view controllers, in the first one i have a button that has to go to a server and do some work, i want to show an alert view containing a spinning indicator, that will show up as soon as the button is pressed and dismissed when the second view controller loads. 
[image]

I tried this way :

```
    - (IBAction)logMeInFunction:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView  *waitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait...." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitAlert show];

  /* Do Some Api testing and stuff */
    [waitAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"logMe" sender: self];
}
```

Using this way, the alert show's up and dismisses instantly in the second view controller, not show's up in the first to inform the user that some work is being done and disappears in the second. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show your server call ? The best option would be to hide that alertview when the call is done and not when the second viewcontroller loads.

Comment: What are you doing in the background? Probably asynchronous tasks i guess. You should wait until the login task, like a `NSURLConnection` is complete and switch views afterwards.

Comment: this is how i am getting json response :
 NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyURL"];
    NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL2]];
    
    NSString *strResult2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    
    NSDictionary *json2 = [strResult2 JSONValue];
  NSMutableArray *userExists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
How can i accomplish what you are suggesting ? this is my first JSon interaction application @chrisblomm

Comment: @Justafinger kindly check my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that your server call needs to be asynchronous. You are now  using dataWithContentsOfURL which is synchronous and which blocks your main thread.

An simple option would be to make that call in a other thread.

```
UIAlertView  *waitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait...." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[waitAlert show];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

     NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyURL"]; 
     NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL2]]; 
     NSString *strResult2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
     NSDictionary *json2 = [strResult2 JSONValue]; 
     NSMutableArray *userExists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         [waitAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"logMe" sender: self];
     });
});
```

Comment: I get this error : *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:388
2014-04-15 11:57:21.574 score2Win[7060:1003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: how can i fix it? @Justafinger

Comment: Well, it works for me... have you replaced your full code with mine ?

Comment: I figured out the problem ! i was accidentally calling the UIAlertView twice!

Comment: I accidentally called the waitAlert twice m that was caused the problem, thank you for you amazing help ! @Justafinger and here's an up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing UIAlertview, show the Custome UIView with the label and indicator...
try the below code...

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,200.0,200.0)];
customView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
customView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
customView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:customView];

UILabel* loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin, 200.0, 100.0)];
[loadingLabel setNumberOfLines:4];
[loadingLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[loadingLabel setText:@"Loading..."];
[customView addSubview:loadingLabel];

UIActivityIndicatorView* loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftMargin + 75.0, topMargin + 45.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
[loadingIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[customView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
```

once the server work finished hide/remove the custom view and load your next view controller....

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you need to `utilize background thread`. The main thread will run a [HUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) and the background thread will hit server and perform operation.

Psuedo Code:

```
-(void)sendRequestToServer
{
     // TODO: Call server to do some function

     // Once you are done with server action, you have to come back to MAIN THREAD
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideHUD) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (IBAction)logMeInFunction:(id)sender 
{
   [MBProgresssHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendRequestToServer) withObject:nil];
}


-(void)hideHUD
{
 [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

NOTE:

Please look at the examples given in the clink and also have a look at `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` blocks.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To possibilities:

1) UIAlertView or any other view with animation will take some mili second time to present itself on screen. So it might be possible that your service call is quick here and gives you response back before even UIAlertView present on screen.

2) UIAlertView needs a time to display on screen, so might be possible that your server call makes UIAlertview wait until web service execution done as both are performing on main thread. So you should wither use delay to call service function after displaying alert view or you should use GCD.